# Call index functions inside a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I've an angular 4 app, in the index.html file, I've a lot of html elements before and after the ng app, since it's just an widget/component for the website.

In the head section of index file, it loads some css and js libraries, such as jquery, bootstrap, etc..

In order to style the select and option tags I'm using the **bootstrap-select**.

The issue is: the select boxes that are hard coded in the index file, works fine, but the ones that are inside the angular app, only work at the beginning.

If I use the ***ngIf** directive to hide and show the element, when it's added again, it doesn't call the 2 functions that are in the index file.

*index.html*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($('.select_box').length > 0){initializeSelectPicker();}
    });

    $(window).load(function(){
        if ($('.select_box').length > 0){adjustSelectPicker();}
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($('.select_box').length > 0){adjustSelectPicker();}
    });

    function initializeSelectPicker(){
        $('.select_box').selectpicker({});
    }

    function adjustSelectPicker(){

        $(this).find(".btn-group.bootstrap-select.select_box.show-tick .btn.dropdown-toggle.selectpicker.btn-default .filter-option.pull-left").css("width", "0");

        $(this).each(function(){
            var maxWidthBox = $(this).find(".btn-group.bootstrap-select.select_box.show-tick .btn.dropdown-toggle.selectpicker.btn-default").width() - 20;
            $(this).find(".btn-group.bootstrap-select.select_box.show-tick .btn.dropdown-toggle.selectpicker.btn-default .filter-option.pull-left").css("width", maxWidthBox + "px");
        });
    }
</script>
```

There is any way to call them in the **ngOnChanges** of a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont recommend this approach, but this can be solved with emitting an event and listen to the desired eventname in your index file.

index file:

```
window.addEventListener('ngFix', function(e) {
// call either one of the methods you wish to run.
});
```

Somewhere in your component you'd have to emit the event, presumably where the input value for the if directive is changed.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ngFix'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Shane van den Bogaard, witch way do you recommend? Using bootstrap inside angular with identical functions?

Comment: I would recommend to write the application in Angular and not just some part of your app. You can load bootstrap styles in an Angular component. I would wrap those elements that you're trying to fix in a custom component and deal with initialization and window resizes within the component.